# PySide: set width of QVBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyside

With PySide, I have a set of QWidget in a QVBoxLayout

```
vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
vlayout.addWidget(self.a_label)
vlayout.addWidget(self.a)
```

I can set the width of widget with

```
self.a.setFixedWidth(60)
```

but If I try set the width of `QVBoxLayout` with `setGeometry`

```
vlayout.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 100, 100))
```

I don't get changes.

How I can set the width of a QVBoxLayout ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved, putting the `QVBoxLayout` in a `QWidget` and fixed the width of QWidget

```
v_widget = QWidget()
v_widget.setLayout(vlayout)
v_widget.setFixedWidth(80)
```